# Write $5 \cos \theta+(75)^{1 / 2} \sin \theta$ in the form $R\sin(\theta+\varepsilon)$, $R>0$

Tags: trigonometry

What is this topic called , as in what should I read inorder to be able to answer this. I know its some form of trig identity but I think these have a specific name

Comment: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/Simplifying_a_sin(x)_%2B_b_cos(x)

Answer (score 4):

All you need to know is the formula for $\sin(x+y)$

$$5\cos\theta+(75)^{1/2}\sin\theta=5\cos\theta+5\sqrt 3\sin\theta=10(\frac 12\cos\theta+\frac{\sqrt 3}2\sin\theta)=10(\sin\frac\pi 6\cos\theta+\cos\frac\pi 6\sin\theta)$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I believe so , thanks let me have at it

Comment: In general, problems like writing $a\cos x+b\sin x$ as $R\sin(x+y)$ requires identifying $a,b$ as $R\sin\theta$ and $R\cos\theta$ respectively for some $R,\theta$

Comment: Note that you can find $R$ instantly as $R=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$; for your problem, we have $R=\sqrt{5^2+75}=\sqrt{100}=10$.